# Scraping using Mechanize and BS4

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to scrape articles from the Wall Street Journal. This involves logging in using mechanize and scraping using BeautifulSoup. I was hoping someone could take a look at my code and explain to me why it's not working.

I am using python 2.7 on a 2012 MacBook Pro running the latest software. I'm new to python so explain to me like I'm 5. Any advice would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cookielib
import mechanize

#Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

#Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj) 

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False) 

# User-Agent 
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.set_debug_http(True) # Print HTTP headers.
# Want more debugging messages?
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://id.wsj.com/access/pages/wsj/us/login_standalone.html?mg=id-wsj')

# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# User credentials
br.form['username'] = 'username'
br.form['password'] = 'password' 

# Login
br.submit()

#br.open("http://online.wsj.com/home-page")
br.open("http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304626304579506924089231470?mod=WSJ_hp_LEFTTopStories&mg=reno64-wsj&url=http%3A%2F%2Fonline.wsj.com%2Farticle%2FSB10001424052702304626304579506924089231470.html%3Fmod%3DWSJ_hp_LEFTTopStories&cb=logged0.9458705162058179")
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
title = soup.find('h1')
print title
```

Comment: No error output, just returns 'none'